# PHP Json Youtube API - How to get author?

Tags: php, json, youtube

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to access the author of a youtube video.

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$id = "xVGVrm-deuM";
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$id}?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);

echo $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'author'}->{'0'}->{'name'}->{'$t'};
```

When I print_r($JSON_Data), the data I get for the author is like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [version] => 1.0
    [encoding] => UTF-8
    [entry] => stdClass Object
        (
            [author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$t] => MrBmacwilliam
                                )

                            [uri] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$t] => https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MrBmacwilliam
                                )

                            [yt$userId] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$t] => cHkE3jhQsHzEHpNavuqIJw
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Please help me to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

echo $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->**{'author'}[0]**->{'name'}->{'$t'};